# how can I use a CASE with an alias defined befor case?

Tags: oracle, case, alias

how can I use an alias like `pop` in a further `case` like in this example (Oracle database).

```
select  
   (select sum(ccs_pop) from rap4) as pop,
case 
    when pop+x=a+b+c then pop+x
end as sum1,
case 
    when pop+y=d+e+f then pop+y
end as sum2
from rap4
```

The ideea is that I need "pop" in a complex situation and I need "pop" in many sentences and I need to use an alias or something...

Comment: Use the column, `ccs_pop`, not the alias (`pop`).

Comment: ok, but, I gave a simple example, what if ccs_pop is a complex sum within a select, etc

Comment: Use the complex expression then. Or write the query you have problem, and we can answer with other alternatives.

Comment: a cannot do that - it's too complex and it's used in many other sentences/etc

Comment: I search for a solution before I make a view with "pop" and I use another view to use the sum in pop...

Comment: You mean you don't want to. Of course you can. It's a simple copy-paste ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, I'll take the provided example, and modify it a bit:

```
select  
    (<insanely complex expression>) as pop,
    case 
        when pop is null then 'isnull'
    end
from rap4 ;
```

The above will of course produce an error because an alias defined in the `SELECT` list, cannot be used in another expression in the same `SELECT` list or the (same level) `WHERE` or `GROUP BY` clauses.

What you can do however is either duplicate the expression:

```
select  
    (<insanely complex expression>) as pop,
    case 
        when <insanely complex expression> is null then 'isnull'
    end
from rap4 ;
```

or use a derived table:

```
select
    pop,
    case 
        when pop is null then 'isnull'
    end
from 
    ( select  
          (<insanely complex expression>) as pop
      from rap4
    ) t ;
```

or use a common table expression (CTE):

```
with cte as
  ( select  
        (<insanely complex expression>) as pop
    from rap4
 )
select
    pop,
    case 
        when pop is null then 'isnull'
    end
from cte ;
```

Comment: I used the common table expression (CTE), thanks!